# How to unlock multiple files at once

Tags: osx-lion, finder

On a Mac with OS X Lion I'm editing a bunch of photos in Preview via the Finder, and any that haven't been edited for a while pop up with an annoying choice of Unlock, Cancel or Duplicate. Well how can I select the whole folder and unlock them all?

Comment: In general it doesn't bother me, it's only noticeable when operating on a bunch of files that you haven't worked on for 2 weeks.

Comment: I can't test it, but maybe the annoying info is stored in some extended attribute with the files. Can you do a `ls -l@` on such a photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command line tool 'touch' works. This changes the last modified date on the file and thereby stops the autosave popup.

```
touch *.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

put files into one folder and run

```
sudo chflags -R nouchg path/to/directory
```

Comment: I tried that but the annoying popups persist. touch *.jpg works, but I still get a bunch of annoying "autosave could not save document". I've just set the autosave date to 1 year to shut it up.

Comment: -1, obviously it doesn't work, and the `uchg` flag has nothing to do with it since it's been available much longer than the Auto-Save feature of Lion.

Comment: Sure works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even if don't use Time Machine, the preference in "System Preferences > Time Machine > Options > Lock documents" is still valid, and is enabled by default :S So, uncheck this to stop this behavior.

If it is locked in the same way downloaded files are, you can unlock them by removing the ._* files. Do the following in terminal:

```
cd /path/to/parent_folder
find . -name "._*" -exec rm '{}' ';'
```

it will ask for the administrator password. If you received no message after entering the password, it worked and your files should be unlocked.

**NOTE:** Be careful with the second command as it will delete all the files matched by the find. You can chech which files will be delete by running only

```
find . -name "._*"
```

Comment: damn that's a dangerous command to type, if you make a mistake, boom :)

Comment: @justinhj You can replace `rm` with `echo` and see what it'd remove.

Comment: @justinhj I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: @slhck this also works for downloaded files :)